# How to dynamically extend the interface or type of an object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, glamorous

I am trying to use PayPal's Glamorous CSS-in-JS library in a boilerplate project I'm building which also leverages TypeScript.

Glamorous allows you to add props to an element like-so:

```
const Section = glamorous.section([
  {
    ...styles
  },
  ({size}: any){
    if(size === 'big') return {fontSize: '48px';}
    else if(size === 'small') return {fontSize: '12px';}
  },
  ({alignment}: any){
    if(alignment === 'left') return {textAlign: 'left'}
    else if(alignment === 'right') return {textAlign: 'right'}
  }
]);
```

So that you can then use the element in JSX like this:

```
<Section size="big"></Section>
```

I have a number of props like this that I would like to add to all of my Glamorous-generated elements. So, I've created a helper function that looks like this:

```
export const special = (glam: any, styles: object[]): GBPComp =>{
  return glam([styles as CSSStyleDeclaration[], specialProps]);
};
```

Where `specialProps` represents a function (like the one above) that adds the various props to my array of style declarations.

I intend to use it like this:

```
const Section = special(glamorous.section, [
  {
    ...styles
  }
]);
```

I then want all of the props provided by `specialProps` to be typed for my JSX usage. So, I've tried to create my `GBPComp` type like this:

```
export type GBPComp = React.StatelessComponent<CSSProperties&ExtraGlamorousProps&React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>&{
  layout?: string,
  width?: string
}>;
```

The issue arises with the fact that not all of the elements returned will necessarily have a property of `React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>`. They may be `HTMLAnchorElement` or `HTMLTableElement`, etc.

How might I be able to generate my `GBPComp` type dynmically, such that it adds those props (i.e. `layout` and `width`) to all returned types? Such that the following will work properly within TypeScript:

```
const Section = special(glamorous.section, [
  {
    ...styles
  }
]);

const Anchor = special(glamorous.a, [
  {
    ...styles
  }
]);

<a href="#" layout="someString">This is an Anchor</a>

<section layout="someString">This is a Section</section>
```

Comment: I wrote https://typestyle.github.io/ specifically for TypeScript convenience 

Comment: Doesn't quite answer my question, but thank you for sharing! TypeStyle looks really cool! :) Starred & watching. May definitely consider it for a future project.

Comment: Yeah, not an answer. Just a comment for your alternative consideration.

Comment: Apparently there are 2 questions
1) The issue arises with the fact that not all of the elements returned will necessarily have a property of React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>. They may be HTMLAnchorElement or HTMLTableElement, etc.
2) How might I be able to generate my GBPComp type dynmically, such that it adds those props (i.e. layout and width) to all returned types?
And seems like 2nd question is already handled by your code, no? layout and witdth are already props of Section and Anchor in your last example.

Comment: Also how could this function work?

`export const special = (glam: any, styles: object[]): GBPComp =>{
  return glam([styles as CSSStyleDeclaration[], specialProps]);
};`

specialProps is not defined here.

Shouldn't it be

`export const special = (glam: any, styles: object[], ...specialProps): GBPComp => {
  return glam([styles as CSSStyleDeclaration[], ...specialProps]);
};` instead?

Comment: @paibamboo You are correct. I didn't define `specialProps` in my question. As I mentioned above, it's representative of a function similar to the one's in my first codeblock (i.e. for `size` & `alignment`). Thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want `React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>` for every elements, instead of hardcoding `React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>`, you could use generics for your `GBPComp` like so

```
export type GBPComp<ExtraProps> = React.StatelessComponent<React.CSSProperties & ExtraGlamorousProps & ExtraProps & { 
  layout: string,
  width: string
}>;
```

And `special()` also accepts `ExtraProps` as generics and pass to `GBPComp` like so

```
export function special<ExtraProps>(glam: any, styles: object[], ...specialProps): GBPComp<ExtraProps> {
  return glam([styles as CSSStyleDeclaration[], ...specialProps]);
};
```

Now you can assign `React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>` props to your `Anchor`

```
const Anchor = special<React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>>(glamorous.a, [
  {
    ...styles
  }
]);
```

Comment: Hmm -- this doesn't quite answer the question of how to define that type dynamically. I'd prefer to not have to add the type on each call of `special`. However, I've voted up your answer as I think generics are definitely a step in the right direction. I hadn't considered this (nor is it something I've been particularly familiar with in TypeScript; at least not writing from scratch). So, thank you! I have moved on to a different piece of the project for now, but I will circle back to this very soon and will definitely update this post if I find generics help me with the solution.